# Docker で DigitalOcean Container Registry のプライベートレジストリにログインできない。

Tags: docker

DigitaloceanのContainer registryを使ってDockerのプライベートリポジトリを運用しているのですが、下記3つの方法でログインを試み、`docker pull`を実行したのですが、成功しませんでした。

1 DigitaloceanのCLI`doctl`を使ってリポジトリにログイン

下記コマンドでログインを試みましたが、DigitaloceanのGUI上にアクセストークンが生成され、`.docker/config.json`が生成されますが、`docker pull`実行時に`unauthorized`エラーが出ました。

```
doctl registry login
```

2 GUIでアクセストークンを生成後それを`.docker/config.json`にコピペ
この方法でも上記と同様の結果になりました。

3 `docker login repositry.digitalocean.com`を実行
上記コマンドを実行してメールアドレス、パスワードを入力しましたが下記の出力を得ました。

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.digitalocean.com/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required
```

あらゆる手段を試しましたがpullすることができませんでした。
Digitalocean container registryを利用中の方、ログイン方法を教えて下さい。
また、Digitaloceanに限らず、プライベートリポジトリへのアクセス方法はこれであっていますでしょうか。
ご教授ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3番の方法でユーザ名とパスワードを両方APIキーにしたところログインできました。